# PHP - Connecting via TCP socket to smart home device - encrypt

Tags: php, sockets, encryption

I am trying to read data from a smart home device (TP-Link HS110)
here is the reverse engineering

https://www.softscheck.com/en/reverse-engineering-tp-link-hs110/

so I have to decrypt and encrypt.
I use the following code but I get no result from the device

this is the output

```
            Socket created 
            Connection established 
            Message send successfully 
            Lenght: 0 Buffer:
            decrypt: 
            Message received successfully
```

here my code

```
            <?php

            function decrypt($string){
                $key = 171;
                $result = "";
                for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
                    $a = $key ^ ord($i);
                    $key = ord($i);
                    $result .= chr($a);
                }
                return $result;
            }

            function encrypt($string){
                $key = 171;
                $result = "\0\0\0\0";
                for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){ 
                    $a = $key ^ ord($i);
                    $key = $a;
                    $result .= chr($a);
                }
                return $result;
            }

            if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP))){
                $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }

            echo "Socket created \n";

            //Connect socket to remote server
            if(!socket_connect($sock , '192.168.178.77' , 9999)){
                $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                $errormsg  = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }

            echo "Connection established \n";

            $message = encrypt('{"system":{"get_sysinfo":{}}}');

            //Send the message to the server
            if(!socket_send ($sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0)){
                $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                $errormsg  = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }

            echo "Message send successfully \n"; 

            //Now receive reply from server
            if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 2048 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE){
                $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
            }

            //print the received message
            echo "Lenght: " . strlen($buf) . " Buffer:" . $buf; 
            echo "\ndecrypt: " . decrypt($buf);
            echo "\nMessage received successfully \n"; 
            socket_close($sock);
            ?>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: you could try to create `$buf` with something like `$buf = 'test'` before calling `socket_recv`.. recently came upon something similar when reference couldn't be passed. But i doubt this comes from this, as you seem to have no error

Comment: I already tried 
`$buf = "Test";    `
but still the same result

Comment: I found a different solution
[link]https://github.com/RobertShippey/hs100-php-api/blob/master/utils.php